# I am interested in pursuing a Masters/PhD program in the US but I do not have a bachelor’s degree

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, masters

My interest is in the field of Psychology/Neuroscience. I am currently a monk/meditation teacher and I dedicated my life to helping people find inner happiness and peace 20 years ago when I was still in high school. Will this vast experience of working with people for 2 decades qualify as field experience and earn me an entry into a graduate/PhD program? I have gained spiritual insights in the nature of the mind and emotions; what I am now looking for is the scientific backing for all my experiences. I want to blend spirituality, Psychology  and neuroscience and develop effectiveness be methods for happiness and inner peace. I read some replies that it is indeed possible to directly enroll for a graduate program. Could someone please guide me how do I go about it? I live in India and I am planning to appear for GRE and TOEFL in August this year.

Comment: Why don't you apply for a bachelor's program first?

Comment: Please check out this link: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/44007/88774

Comment: This is what got me interested. There are a variety of reasons why I seek to ‘expedite’ my process of education. One reason being my age. The other reason being my financial limitations. I have not worked for profit all these years.

Answer (score 3):

Your experience is not in science, why would you have equivalence in any science related bachelor degree?

I am completely sure that your experience on religion/spirituality/self-help/alternative therapies/human interactions will not guarantee equivalence in psychology or neuroscience related degrees. The knowledge expected from a person holding one of these degrees is completely different.

However, instead of pursuing a PhD why not engage in a bachelor course? The bachelor will give to you many tools of which you will need to work in a PhD.

Comment: If you check out details of Princeton’s Neuroscience/Psychology joint graduation program, you are not expected to hold a bachelor’s in science or psychology as a prerequisite. You only need to have a bachelor’s- it could even be in business studies or art history. Their website itself says that there will be a foundational course in Neuroscience that is mandatory.

Comment: I posed this question because I happened to read someone’s post on this site that they were selected for a masters/PhD course even when they did not complete their bachelor’s degree. If I read it right, they dropped out after the first year of their undergraduation program, took a 10 year long break from education and gained a lot of hands on work experience and then resumed education with a masters program. And they were also mentioning that every university quietly admits 1-2 students like this every year after having verified their credentials.